# Friendly canonical urls for paginated pages using kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-tags, kaminari, canonical-link

Currently I'm using following method for posts pages to generate canonical url

```
posts_url(page: params[:page])
```

and it generates `http://localhost:3000/posts?page=2` and I want to have url as **`http://localhost:3000/posts/page/2`**.

and using **`rel_next_prev_link_tags @posts`** to generate prev and next rel tags, and it generates urls without query strings.

Is there a method in kaminari or rails which can give correct canonical url for the current page without query strings.

Thanks

Comment: dont use the erb tags..use pure html instead and customise the html generated and pass it as http://localhost:3000/posts/page/2....

Comment: @Milind are you suggesting to use "#{posts_url()}/page/#{@posts.current_page}"

Comment: yes...because if you are using helpers then the url will not the one that you need..so use dynamic code and try it out...  @StarWars

Comment: ok... implemented it, thanks :)

Comment: ...good to know it.....Can you please click on the arrow ...to accept what i suggested...?i will truly appreciate it